# Hacer un .jar y poder mandarlo sin el código fuente y que se ejecute sin problema

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Java y estoy usando como IDE Netbeans. Quiero compilar el proyecto (crear el .jar) y que se pueda distribuir a varias personas por correo electrónico y se ejecute en las máquinas SIN MANDAR EL CÓDIGO FUENTE.

El proyecto permite crear, modificar y eliminar archivos .txt de donde jala la información mientras se ejecuta. Cómo le puedo hacer para crear el .jar y que cree, modifique sin problemas durante la ejecución? (Suponiendo que a todos los que se lo mando tienen instalado java en sus computadoras)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Haz clic derecho en el nombre del proyecto del cual quieras generar un archivo JAR y selecciona “Properties” (propiedades) en el menú despegable.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Marca la casilla que dice “Compress JAR file” (comprimir archivo JAR). En tu ventana de propiedades, observa la lista de categorías a la izquierda de la ventana. En la sección de “Build” (generar), verás la opción de “Packaging” (empaquetando), haz clic en ella. Marca la casilla llamada “Compress JAR file” que se ubica a la derecha.

Comment: Eso no es la pregunta, la pregunta es como puede generar un `.jar` excluyendo el código fuente.

Comment: La opción que mencionas solo tiene que ver con la compresión del .jar. No tiene nada que ver con el que se genere el .jar o no.

Answer (score 0):

Aun que no te puedo decir si hay una opción en NetBeans para excluir el código fuente, te puedo dar una solución fuera de NetBeans.

Un `jar` es nada más que un caso forma especial de un `.zip` con unas reglas de organisación. Así puedes abrir un `.jar` generado con un una herramienta de compresión como por ejemplo `7zip` y borrar los archivos `.java`, dejando solamente los archivos `.class` que ya estan en bytecode.

Consideras trabajar con otra IDE para tener opciónes más faciles de manejar el tema de generar jars a tus necesidades?

Answer (score 0):

Muy probablemente ya tienes el *.jar* que pides, pero tal vez simplemente no te has dado cuenta.

Cuando haces un *Build* en *Netbeans*, por defecto automáticamente te genera una archivo *.jar* (sin el código fuente) en un sub-directorio **dist**. (Si no lo hace, verifica las propiedades de tu proyecto bajo *Packaging*, y asegúrate de que la opción *Build JAR after Compiling* está seleccionada)

Por ejemplo, si tu proyecto Netbeans se encuentra en un directorio **c:\proyectos\miapp**, cuando hagas un *Build* verás que Netbeans crea un archivo *.jar* en el lugar siguiente: **c:\proyectos\miapp\dist\miapp.jar**.

Es más, si tu aplicación depende de librerías adicionales, estas se encontrarán en el directorio siguiente: **c:\proyectos\miapp\dist\lib**.

De modo que si quieres que otras personas puedan ejecutar tu aplicación en otras computadoras que tienen Java instalado, simplemente necesitas mandarles el contenido completo del directorio **dist**.

Para ejecutar el archivo *.jar*:

```
java -jar <directorio-y-nombre-del-archivo>.jar
```

Ejemplo:

```
java -jar c:\proyectos\miapp\dist\miapp.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

**Click derecho en el proyecto que quieres compilar**, luego en la opción **Clean And Build**, luego vas al directorio de tu proyecto(Por defecto **Mis documentos/Netbeans Projects/NombreDeTuProyecto**), abres la carpeta **dist**, y encontraras un archivo **Jar** listo para su distribución.

Answer (score 0):

1) Comúnmente se genera el .jar con la "compilación" en la carpeta dist de tu proyecto.

2) Algunos problemas en la generación del .jar podrían presentarse (si se han incluido espacios y/o tildes en el nombre del proyecto, dependiendo del SO, y de la forma de compilar, etc.) si se usa netbeans: click derecho en proyecto, prperties, build, packaging, check compress jar file, check build jar after Compiling, OK, clean and build.

3) Si lo que te preocupa es el código fuente deberías informarte acerca de las opciones de **ofuscación** en java, por ejemplo buscar en google el programa proguard.

Comment: proguard se usa  para ofuscar el bytecode (*.class) El codigo fuente (*.java) normalmente no se incluye en un jar

Comment: Tendríamos que comentar que Proguard sirve para más que las class; que se puede probar JD-Gui sobre un jar y ver; y que se debe conocer la "compilación" en java.